# How to check that invalid data in database for enum

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, exception

I have the following field declaration:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ConnectionInformation implements Serializable {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    private ConnectionType connectionType;
    ....
}
```

In database `connectionType` is `varchar` field user can type any string there.

I have a requirement that I should log specific error if user types something wrong at this field.

How can I check it in java code when I read entity from database?

now my dao method throws

```
 Unknown name value [trololo] for enum class [package.ConnectionType] 
    .... 
    'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException' exception.
```

I am afraid that I cannot rely on exception type. exception can be thrown for another field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it will be better, if you map `connectionType` as a `String` type

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ConnectionInformation implements Serializable {

    @Column
    private String connectionType;

    @Transient  
    public ConnectionType getConnectionTypeAsEnum() {
        return connectionType == null ? null : ConnectionType.valueOf(connectionType); 
    }

    public void assertConnectionType() {
        try {
            getConnectionTypeAsEnum();
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Invalid `connectionType`: %s", conectionType), ex);  
        }      
    }

}
```